# org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: hadoop, out-of-memory, hive

I am running a simple join query

```
select count(*) from t1 join t2 on t1.sno=t2.sno
```

However it's giving an out of memory exception.

Both `t1` and `t2` are in `rcfile` format clustered and sorted on ssn and have 20 million records each. I have 3 data nodes with 4 GB ram and 2 CPU cores.

I have tried running a map join but its also failing.

The other configuration options are:

```
io.sort.mb- 500 MB
io.sort.factor- 10
fs.memory.size.mb- 500 MB
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure the property mapred.child.java.opts, as showed at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464048/out-of-memory-error-in-hadoop)