# running an elementary mapreduce job with java on hadoop

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, netbeans, hadoop

I am just getting started with linux/java/hadoop/EMR.

I am following [this](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781849517287/1dot-getting-hadoop-up-and-running-in-a-cluster/ch01s03_html?reader=html#X2ludGVybmFsX0h0bWxWaWV3P3htbGlkPTk3ODE4NDk1MTcyODclMkZjaDAxczAzX2h0bWwmcXVlcnk9) neat book.

The assignment is to run:

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-cookbook-chapter1.jar chapter1.WordCount input output
```

And this is the response that I get:

```
alex@HadoopMachine:/usr/share/hadoop$ sudo hadoop jar hadoop-cookbook-chapter1.jar chapter1.WordCount input output
13/05/01 01:01:08 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/05/01 01:01:08 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/05/01 01:01:08 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/05/01 01:01:09 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
13/05/01 01:01:09 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
13/05/01 01:01:09 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@1c04d881
13/05/01 01:01:09 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
13/05/01 01:01:09 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0001
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.<init>(MapTask.java:949)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
13/05/01 01:01:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/05/01 01:01:10 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
13/05/01 01:01:10 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
```

Frankly, since I have almost no java background, I do not even know where to start debugging.

I would be most grateful for any guidance on how to tackle this issue.

**update**

after following greedybuddha's advice i am getting:

```
    alex@HadoopMachine:/usr/share/hadoop$ sudo hadoop jar hadoop-cookbook-chapter1.jar chapter1.WordCount -Dmapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1G input output
[sudo] password for alex: 
13/05/01 11:03:54 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/05/01 11:03:54 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/05/01 11:03:54 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/05/01 11:03:54 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
13/05/01 11:03:54 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
13/05/01 11:03:54 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@35756b65
13/05/01 11:03:54 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
13/05/01 11:03:54 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0001
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.<init>(MapTask.java:949)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
13/05/01 11:03:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/05/01 11:03:55 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
13/05/01 11:03:55 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464048/out-of-memory-error-in-hadoop for different approaches to the problem.

Comment: @harpun would i need to restart for that??

Comment: @harpun thank you! i tried, but still geting the same issue. one user says to restart daemon, how can i do that?

Comment: I don't know which option you tried. In case you changed `mapred-site.xml`, you have to restart the hadoop daemons using `stop-all.sh` and `start-all.sh`.

Comment: @harpun i edited the xml file. is it safe to run stop-all? wouldnt i want to only restart the hadoop daemons?

Comment: stop-all.sh is a script, which you can find in the `bin` folder of your hadoop installation. It stops all hadoop daemons (namenode, datanode, jobtracker, tasktracker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java needs a certain amount of memory to run programs.  When a program uses too much, it will throw the error you are having.  The solution is to tell java to allocate more memory for the program.  In this case you should be able to tell hadoop to allocate you the memory.  Try the following.

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-cookbook-chapter1.jar chapter1.WordCount -Dmapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1G input output
```

the option -Xmx1G says allow up 1 Gigabyte.

This other stackoverflow question is also very similar. 
[out of Memory Error in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464048/out-of-memory-error-in-hadoop)

Comment: thanks so much for your help. now i am getting this exception": Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -Dmapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1G
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:

Comment: Apologies, the -Doption.to.set=somevalue, should come after the name of the program to run.  I updated my answer above to reflect this.

Comment: thank you . i am getting a new JAVA HEAP SPACE error. please see updated question

Comment: It looks like the same one, try with even more memory, like 2G, if that's not enough then you have a different problem then what my solution would solve.

Comment: perhaps hadoop requires more ram? how can i find out?

Comment: I found this other question on stackoverflow that is nearly the same. Check out the answer by Zach Garner, maybe that's your case as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464048/out-of-memory-error-in-hadoop

Comment: thank you! i tried, but still geting the same issue. one user says to restart daemon, how can i do that?

Comment: You will need to stop that NameNode and DataNode daemons.The paths might be slightly different for you as I usuaully run 0.23. sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh stop secondarynamenode
sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh stop datanode
sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh stop namenode

Comment: thank you very much again. it says for each one no datanode to stop, no namenode tostop, no secondarynamenode to stop

Comment: however, when i get a list of all daemons, it gives me: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4516 Oct  2  2012 hadoop-datanode
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4428 Oct  2  2012 hadoop-historyserver
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4365 Oct  2  2012 hadoop-jobtracker
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4556 Oct  2  2012 hadoop-namenode
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4527 Oct  2  2012 hadoop-secondarynamenode
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4393 Oct  2  2012 hadoop-tasktracker

Comment: anymore hints? sorry, newbie at linux / java / hadoop!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29261/discussion-between-greedybuddha-and--)