# Use wget with Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, wget

I have a dataset (~31GB, zipped file with extension .gz) which is present on a web location, and I want to run my Hadoop program on it. The program is a slight modification from the original WordCount example that comes shipped with Hadoop. In my case, Hadoop is installed on a remote machine (to which I connect via ssh and then run my jobs). The problem is that I can't transfer this large dataset to my home directory on the remote machine (due to disk usage quota). So, I tried searching for if there's a way to use wget to get the dataset and directly pass it onto the HDFS (without saving on my local acccount on the remote machine), but no luck.
Does such a way even exist? Any other suggestions to get this working?

I've already tried using Yahoo! VM which comes pre-configured with Hadoop, but it's too slow and plus runs out of memory since the dataset is large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the answer here: [putting a remote file into hadoop without copying it to local disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270509/putting-a-remote-file-into-hadoop-without-copying-it-to-local-disk)

You can pipe the data from wget to hdfs.

However, you will have a problem - gz is not splittable so you won't be able to run a distributed map/reduce on it.

I suggest you download the file locally, unzip it and then either pipe it in or split it into multiple files and load them into hdfs.

Comment: Thanks. I'd gone through that thread already that's why I mentioned .gz extension specifically. But since you mentioned that .gz is not splittable that way (which answers my question), I think I have no other option but to download that file locally first.