# Hadoop Mapper filling with MapOutputBuffer objects, is there a better way to skip bad keys?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm working on a mapreduce project where I cannot guarantee beforehand that my mapper will always be given a usable keyvalue pair.  I tried surrounding the relevant code with a try catch block like so

```
public void map(LongWritable Key, Text values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            try {
                    //Attempt process

                    context.write(HKey, HValue);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //was given invalid value, drop it and move on
                context.nextKeyValue();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Memory profiling this on a large dataset reveals that MapOutputBuffers are taking up most of my memory, giving me an eventual out of memory error.  Is there a better way to structure my Mapper so I dont have this issue?  I'd rather not have to allocate extra memory as a stopgap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that printing stack trace is useless, I am using this code:

```
// Define enumeration    
    public static enum LOCAL_COUNTER_MAP {
                INVALID 
            }   


        public void map(LongWritable Key, Text values, Context context)
                            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                        try {
                                //Attempt process

                                context.write(HKey, HValue);

                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        // ignore value
                          context.getCounter(LOCAL_COUNTER_MAP.INVALID).increment(1);
                          return;
                        }
            }
```

In your job result you will than see how many of mappers had invalid keyvalue pair.

Good luck :)

Comment: The printing stack trace isnt really the issue, although thats a really good way to handle that.  I'm gonna do it to stop my log files from ballooning.  Anyway the issue is that even when I skipped over bad values using a return statement I ran into a gc overhead limit.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that the process spent more than 98% in garbage collection and the less than 2% of heap is recovered. So try to increase heap size, look at this post, think it can help - [Out of memory error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464048/out-of-memory-error-in-hadoop)

Comment: Well it seems to be working now, its strange, I thought I set that in the hadoop-env file.  I do wonder if there is some other memory issue I can fix but this is more then enough for now.  Thank you.