# on the one of the Hadoop edge node i am getting this error OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, heap-memory

On a server, we are getting this error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method) at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1378) at java.lang.UNIXProcess.initStreams(UNIXProcess.java:288) at java.lang.UNIXProcess.lambda$new$2(UNIXProcess.java:258) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)`

memory is available - checked
Disk space is available - check
I have doubts about heap size.

Can anyone help how to know the heap size usage at regular intervals?

`Exception in thread "main" **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:** unable to create new native thread`

Comment: I am adding full log here:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1378)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.initStreams(UNIXProcess.java:288)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.lambda$new$2(UNIXProcess.java:258)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [out of Memory Error in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464048/out-of-memory-error-in-hadoop)

Comment: You need to show us what Java process you are actually running. It starts with a set amount of heap size.